# Comparing random values in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm self-taught with C++, so forgive me if the answer is really obvious!

I'm writing code for a dice game I came up with a few years back, and I need to be able to compare the values of results. My thought is that if I create an array and assign each of the 5 dice to a point in the array, it should be a simple matter of writing a few lines of code that would check to see if any of the sections are equal.

Here's the trick - I need to be able to check for pairs, triples, quadruples, quintuples, AND double pairs. I don't have the slightest idea how to go about this, and I can't seem to find anything on arrays that would help me. Is using an array the best way to go about this, or is there something easier? Or, would I have to simply write out every combination of comparisons and then go on to the next step?

Here's the (abridged) code I have so far - not much, but it's what I'm working with for now.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int d1;         //die 1
int d2;         //die 2
int d3;         //die 3
int d4;         //die 4
int d5;         //die 5
int dice [5];   //all 5 dice

int sum;        //the sum of all the dice

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    d1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    d2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    d3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    d4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    d5 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    sum = d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5;

    if (dice [] = dice [])
        cout << endl << dice [];

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, `dice []` doesn't work. I'm trying to construct the logic for what I want, and I'm coming up short. Could I use a struct? I'm trying to think of anything, but when it comes to actually comparing the different numbers to see if they're equal, I'm drawing a blank. I feel like there's got to be some way of typing out `if (dice [x.1] = dice [x.2])`, where `dice [x.1]` represents any of the five numbers, and `dice [x.2]` is another.

Comment: Don't compare dice at all, just go through and count the number of 1s, 2s, etc. If any member of this list ==4 you have a quadruple, ==3 a triple, etc.  But more urgently, enroll in a C++ course.  Your code is very C-like and also doesn't really use the data structures well--e.g. `d1`-`d5` are wholly redundant if you have `dice[]`.

Comment: Here's a couple ideas: (1) Get rid of `d1`, `d2`, etc. and just use an array `int d[5]` and access them via `d[0]`, `d[1]` instead. (2) Create a histogram array: `int histogram[6]` initialized to all 0s. After rolling the dice, loop through the `d` array and increment `histogram[d[i]-1]++`. You can then inspect the `histogram` array to check for doubles, triples, etc. E.g. if `histogram[5]==2` then you know there were 2 sixes, etc.

Comment: if you explain the rules of the game would be easier to help you out :) Cheers

Comment: side note: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. if you do `if( dice[0] = dice[2] )`, it is like saying `dice[0] = dice[2]; if( dice[0] )` which will be true because `dice[0]` is non-zero

Comment: @Matt - That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @clcto - Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @prmottajr - Well, the game itself is a bit complicated (it also involves a second set of dice and a deck of playing cards - I'll implement that stuff later on), but in essence, you want the dice to add up to seventeen. If you get pairs of any sort, you get additional rolls of the dice, but not directly. For now, I just need to catalog the results so I can use them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
d2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
d3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
d4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
d5 = rand() % 6 + 1;
```

This should instead be this:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    d[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
```

Then, to count how many instances of each number rolled, try something like this:

```
int dieFaces[6] = {0};
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    dieFaces[d[i]-1]++;
}
```

But we really only even need `d[]` array if the order rolled is important.  If you only need the values of the dies rolled, we can combine the two loops into this:

```
int dieFaces[6] = {0};
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    int face = rand() % 6;
    dieFaces[face]++;
}
```

Either way, after you fill `dieFaces`, you can access the number rolled for any particular die face by accessing the element that is 1 less of the face you're interested in (arrays are 0-indexed).

So, if you want to know how many fives were rolled:

```
int fivesRolled = dieFaces[4];
```

If you want to check if any triples were rolled:

```
bool triplesRolled = false;
for(int i = 0; i<6; ++i) {
    if(dieFaces[i] == 3) {
        triplesRolled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Calculating the sum of the dice:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<6; ++i) {
    sum += ((i+1) * dieFaces[i]);
}
```

Although, I'd probably just calculate sum at the same time as I'm generating the numbers.

Comment: There is an out-of-bounds issue when doing `dieFaces[d[i]]++;`. Just substracting 1 from `d[i]` will solve it.

Comment: Yea, just fixed it. @betabandido

Comment: Perfect! I'm keeping the  `d []` array separate, because part of the game is that you select which dice you're going to re-roll. I just made `int sum = d[0] + ... + d[4];` in a line right after generating the numbers. This offers a lot of insight - thanks, @nhgrif!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of thinking about this is that when you generate the numbers, instead of treating each of the different indices in the array as a separate die, treat each index as the number of dice that rolled that index.
For example, if you have 5 six-sided die and rolled 2, 2, 4, 5, 6 you might have an array that looks like [0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1]. Then, you can just iterate over the array looking for the values of interest to record them.
Of course, if you need to know which dice rolled which value, then this isn't much help, and it isn't particularly flexible for things like having each die have a different number of sides.
Hopefully this will give you an idea about how to approach the problem.

Comment: I do need to keep track of the dice, because I have to select which dice I'm going to re-roll in successive rounds. But thanks anyway!